# Is it possible to access memory using Lua

Tags: memory, lua

I wonder if it's possible to access memory which are used by another program? E.g. given the name(or handle) of program A, can I use Lua to read all memory allocated to A, and then modify the values of some address?

Comment: Are you writing a virus or sniffer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible if you use either a C module providing functions for this or use LuaJIT instead of Lua, and take a look at e.g. https://github.com/nonchip/ljptrace, where i pretty much did exactly what you want